# Question about map() function with list in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am building a simple gallery app that displays pictures. Clicking on one picture will navigate to its respective page.

I have an object like so:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    images: {
      'Mirage':   require('../img/mirage.png'),
      'Inferno':  require('../img/inferno.png'),
      'Train':    require('../img/train.png'),
      'Overpass': require('../img/ovp.png'),
      'Nuke':     require('../img/nuke.png'),
      'Cache':    require('../img/cache.png'),
      'Dust2':    require('../img/dust2.png'),
    }   

  }
}
```

and the render function like this:

```js
render() {
  let images = this.state.images.map((val,key) =>{  
    return <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(...value here...)} key={key}>
        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
            <ImageElement imgsource = {...image url here...}></ImageElement> 
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  });
```

How can I loop through the object and grab the key and value of each member then transfer them into the component? I am new to React Native and the documents Im reading about mapping are all about ReacJS, Im not sure if they are similar.

Dont mind the names haha. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render(){
let images = [];
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.images)) {
  images.push(<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(key)} key={key}>
        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
            <ImageElement imgsource = {value}></ImageElement> 
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>)
}
}
```

Use {images} inside View to render items.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping! do I need to import any React Native library to use the Object.entries() function?

Comment: No you don't have to it. It is Js Method

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)

```
render() {
  const images = Object.entries(this.state.images).map(([key, val]) =>{  
    return <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(...value here...)} key={key}>
        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
            <ImageElement imgsource = {...image url here...}></ImageElement> 
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  });
...
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Do I need to import anything to use the Object functions?

Comment: You're welcome! React Native includes a polyfill for `Object.entries` so no imports are needed (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment)